# INNER JOIN works as CROSS JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have very simple scenario

```
ID |NAME | DEPT_ID
1  |R K  | 1
2  |V K  | 1

DEPT_ID | LOC
1       | KA 
1       | VA
```

Expected output

```
 ID |NAME | DEPT_ID |LOC
 1  |R K  | 1       |KA
 2  |V K  | 1       |VA
```

But,getting

```
ID |NAME | DEPT_ID |LOC
1  |R K  | 1       |KA
2  |V K  | 1       |VA
1  |R K  | 1       |VA
2  |V K  | 1       |KA
```

I have used simple INNER JOIN. I can get my expected output ?

```
select ID,NAME,LOC 
from table1 
    inner join table2 on table1.dept_id=table2.dept_id
```

Comment: Where is the query you have tried?

Comment: The real query is really big.. so I can't write it here but its simple inner join between the tables

Comment: so people here should guess the query??

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What do you want us to provide you?

Comment: so in your second table, you have a department_id with two locations.  How do you know which location goes with which name?  You're missing a key.

Comment: that's the scenario.. i can't do  anything.. that's why i'm asking solution. Any alternative way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First record has dept_id of 1. There are 2 matching records for this dept_id

Second record has dept_id of 1. There are 2 matching records for this dept_id

So total 4 records in the result. It works as expected.

There is no way the server could know that `KA` matches `R K` and not `V K`

Conclusion: don't use non-unique field for the join.

Comment: can you give example ?

Comment: there's no exemple to give. If you join this 2 tables by dept_id, you'll always get 2 rows for each one of yours ID's. That is because DEPT table has non-uniques dept_id